# Set different application id according to environment and need to release to google play or not

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have basic knowledge of `build types` and `product flavors` but still have no idea.

This is my case:

There are three environment `dev`, `stg` and `prod`, with different domain server. I want to install all different environment apks in the same device  when develop.

We can set different `build types` with `applicationIdSuffix`, so they got different application id, and can be installed in the same device.

And now, I need to upload apk to Google Play for our testers. But Google Play requires a unique application id. So I have to delete suffix.

All I need apk are

1. `com.android.example`(with dev server for Google Play)
2. `com.android.example`(with stg server for Google Play)
3. `com.android.example`(with prod server for Google Play)
4. `com.android.example.dev`(with dev server for Development)
5. `com.android.example.stg`(with stg server for Development)
6. `com.android.example.prod`(with prod server for Development.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have different options.
For example use 6 different build types and setting for each of them the applicationId and other parameters like the server url.

```
buildtype1 : com.android.example(with dev server for Google Play)
buildtype2 : com.android.example(with stg server for Google Play)
buildtype3 : com.android.example(with prod server for Google Play)
buildtype4 : com.android.example.dev(with dev server for Development)
buildtype5 : com.android.example.stg(with stg server for Development)
buildtype6 : com.android.example.prod(with prod server for Development.)
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail? I have the same requirement. Where I need to write the above solutions

Comment: @RiddhiShah In the build.gradle script, in the buildtypes block just define the applicationId and other resource you need